# How to handle application temporarily killed and then restarted

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Lets say an application is running with activity B is in top of the stack and activity A is the activity that has the launch intent defined in the manifest. Then my app goes in the background (not visible) and the system temporarily kills my application and brings it back up again.

At that point which activity does the system bring up first, activity A (launch intent defined in the manifest) or activity B ?

Also if the application is temporarily killed then does it restart right away or it might be dead for a while?

My application has a lot of dynamic state, it also logs in to a server, so when the application is temporarily killed then the state of my application can change during that time and when it is restarted I will again have to start my application and re-login and update all its state again. Is there any way this can be avoided?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, If application is killed then it should start from launch activity. If there is login option, then you should keep remember me option too, so that if app is being killed you got the state of app and execute auto login if remember me is set otherwise just launch the app with login process.

Answer (score 0):

I beg to differ from what @Keshav says. I think the Activity that was destroyed last is what is re-created and shown to the user. I base my belief based on what happens when the configuration of the device changes - the current activity is actually destroyed the same is re-created and it's not the very first activity that was launched.

As far as what you should do, guidelines when your app gets terminated or destroyed while it's in background, you have to refer to:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState

Comment: My issue was when the application is killed, not just an activity. Also I just can not save my state and bring it back because while my activity was gone my state has changed and I can not bring back the old saved state.

Comment: When an application is killed, the entire task is terminated. A task is a set of activities and has a back-stack associated with it. So, if the entire task is killed, and if user or the system starts the app again, then a new task (with no activities in it's back-stack) will be created and then what @keshav says will be true. More info on tasks at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> Lets say an application is running with activity B is in top of the
>   stack and activity A is the activity that has the launch intent
>   defined in the manifest. Then my app goes in the background (not
>   visible) and the system temporarily kills my application and brings it
>   back up again.

The following happens:

1. A new process is created for your application
2. Your `Application` object is instantiated and `onCreate()` is called on it
3. An instance of `ActivityB` (the top activity on the task stack) is instantiated and `onCreate()` is called on it

Your root activity (`ActivityA`) will only be instantiated when (and if) `ActivityB` ends (is finished or the user presses the BACK button).

You cannot prevent Android from killing your app while it is in the background. However, you can determine that this has happened and react accordingly. The easiest way to do this is to have a static member variable *either in the root activity or in a custom `Application` class) that you set to `true` when the root activity is created and has performed its initialization. In `onCreate()` of `ActivityB`, check if this variable is set to `true`. If not, your app has been restarted, so you can now react. For example, you could just redirect the user back to the root activity and force start your application from the beginning. Or you could tell the user to wait while you reinitialize your application, etc.